# How to add double and single equation marks to a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I was wondering how I can add a double and single quotation mark to a list in python, thank you. Here is what I have:

`punc_list = [".",":",";",""","'"]`

Comment: hello, well its not really actual code. But I can put I what I tried.

Comment: It isn't clear at all what you are asking.

Comment: Check this link: https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp

Comment: If you're asking about how to make a string that contains a single-quote mark, and another with a double-quote mark, that's something you look up in any tutorial on Python strings.  It's not a Stack Overflow question.  Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: @jay, if either of the answers resolve your question, you should mark it as accepted. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for how to do this. If you just post questions and never accept, people will stop answering them.

Answer (score 0):

```
string_list=['a', 'b', 'c']
string_list.append("'")
string_list.append('"')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two straightforward ways of doing this (there are also plenty of obscure ways, but let's not go there).

The one I usually prefer is just use the opposite type of quote mark to surround the quote-character. That is, if you're trying to specify the *single*-quote (apostrophe, `'`), surround it with *double* quotes: `"'"`; and if you're trying to specify a *double*-quote, surround it with single-quotes: `'"'`.

Using this approach, your statement would look like this:

```
punc_list = [".", ":", ";", '"', "'"]
```

The other approach is to "*escape*" the double-quote with a backslash (`\`) character: `"\""` If you put the backslash in front of the quote-mark, that tells Python not to treat it as a delimiter, and instead use it as an actual quote-mark.

Using this approach, your statement would look like this:

```
punc_list = [".", ":", ";", "\"", "'"]
```

There's a list of supported escapes in the Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).